# WordPress Gallery Permalink Structure Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: attachments, gallery

When an image is added to a gallery, the resulting attachment URL is generally displayed in a structure like this: **example.com/post-slug/attachment-slug/**

However, take a look at my gallery: http://themeforward.com/demo2/?p=2195 and view an image.  What could be preventing this slug from appearing correctly?  The images have been attached to the post properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to edit your settings > permalinks